# How to restrict access to a class to only one thread

Tags: java

I have a class called MathParser which has only one entry point which is "Evaluate" a static function which takes only one String input and outputs the evaluated result. The MathParser class has several booleans representing different functionality that can be switched on or off.

In a single threaded application, The evaluate function will throw exceptions if things are not in desired order, and once it gets hold of the control flow, it will release it only when the processing is done ensuring complete safety from any kind of unexpected behavior.

However, in a Multi-threaded Application, A different thread can also turn this switches on or off independently as they're all static and public variables, while the Evaluate function might still be processing the input. It can lead to all sorts of unexpected behaviors.

So I wanted to know if a class and it's members can be made to be accessible only by one thread, either Main or a background, this way, no other thread will mess up things while processing is still midway.

Comment: No. You should create a new instance for every use. Such a pattern is very common.

Comment: Get rid of the static fields and methods and use a new instance per calculation. You must have very good reasons to want only one calculation going on at the same time, for example very heavy resource usage that can't benefit from multi threading.

Comment: Judging from the replies I may have misunderstood the issue, but you might find ```Semaphore``` useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is crying out for you to make this a class and the `Evaluate()` method non-static along with all the Booleans as non-static fields.

Then you can allocate an instance in a thread and no other thread will have access to it (unless you pass is between threads).

But your alternative is to make the `static` method `synchronized` synchronised `static` methods are exclusive to the class. Only one thread may be executing a synchronized static method on a give class at a time.

You would then make all the setters synchronized (`static synchronized void setXxxx(boolean val)`).

Having (of course) made all the flags private to the class.

Then no other thread can be setting the booleans while the `Evaluate()` method is executing.

**But I can not stress enough that is not the way to go.**
It's not the way to write multi-threaded code because it means that only one thread can be evaluating at any time for no good reason!

There is no logical reason why two threads can't be evaluating at the same time except for your decision that there shall be only one object that has an Evaluate method. That one object being the class `MathParser`.

The static method design may lead to entirely unnecessary resource contention.

It's like a class with only one calculator kept on the teachers desk and everyone has to line up to use it. But calculators are cheap and everyone could have their own.

Each thread can so easily have it's own parser.
The objective in concurrency it maximise parallelism and that means minimise waiting/blocking in which one or more threads cannot proceed until some other thread does something.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was just that I'm addicted to singletons... Static here, static there, static everywhere. Maybe it's time to get rid of bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

Use lock or synchronized :
https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized

You can learn more about that by researching "lock in multithreading".